# Не могу добавить бота в беседу вконтакте (бот написан на python)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Подскажите как добавить бота в беседу во вконтакте. Написан бот на python с использованием vk_api и longpoll.

Answer (score 1):

```
Из документации ВК: 

> 1. Сообщество
Для подключения чат-бота Вы можете использовать любое своё сообщество ВКонтакте — группу, встречу или публичную страницу. Ваш бот должен соответствовать правилам, подробнее о них Вы можете узнать здесь. 

> Первым делом нужно указать, что в вашем сообществе будет работать бот. Для этого перейдите в "Управление сообществом" →"Сообщения" →"Настройки для бота" и включите пункт "Возможности ботов". 

> Сообщество — это точка входа для пользователей, которые будут общаться с Вашим ботом. Стоит позаботиться о том, чтобы оно выглядело привлекательно и содержало описание Вашего бота, иначе его действия могут стать сюрпризом для пользователей. Не забудьте включить сообщения в Вашем сообществе («Управление сообществом» → «Сообщения»), когда бот будет готов к использованию, чтобы ему можно было написать. 

> Итак, если Вы выбрали сообщество, можно приступать к настройке уведомлений. 

> 1.1. Получение ключа доступа
Ключ доступа потребуется Вам для получения обновлений (в Long Poll), а также для работы с API. 

> Откройте раздел «Управление сообществом» («Управление страницей», если у Вас публичная страница), выберите вкладку «Работа с API» и нажмите «Создать ключ доступа». 

>Отметьте необходимые права доступа и подтвердите свой выбор. 



> Вы можете создать несколько ключей с разными правами доступа. Ключи нельзя размещать публично — узнав его, третье лицо может обращаться к API ВКонтакте от имени Вашего сообщества. Если ключ был скомпрометирован, необходимо удалить его из списка — после этого он станет недействителен. 

> Также Вы можете получить ключ доступа с помощью OAuth. Используйте схему авторизации Authorization Code Flow. 


Для добавления в беседы:
> 1.2. Добавление ботов в беседы
Чтобы пользователи смогли добавлять бота в беседы, необходимо включить эту возможность в настройках. Перейдите в «Управление сообществом» →«Сообщения» →«Настройки для бота» и поставьте галочку в пункте «Разрешать добавлять сообщество в беседы». После этого в сообществе появится кнопка «Пригласить в беседу», открывающая модальное окно со списком бесед. 

>Сейчас у бота в беседе есть три уровня доступа: 

>Только упоминания
Этот уровень доступа выдается сразу после добавления в беседу. Бот может:
видеть все сообщения, которые его касаются. Это упоминания бота и ответы на его сообщения
отправлять сообщения в беседу

> Доступ ко всей переписке
> Выдать его может любой администратор беседы. Бот может:
> видеть все сообщения в беседе
> отправлять сообщения в беседу

> Администратор
> Выдать его может только создатель беседы. Бот может:
> видеть все сообщения в беседе
> отправлять сообщения в беседу
> Получать объект беседы
> Получать участников беседы

> Важное замечание: для получения событий из беседы версия API у callback-сервера должна быть не ниже 5.80.
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/345317)

Comment: окей, изменю. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Бота должен либо кто-то пригласить, либо ему нужно "скормить" [ссылку-приглашение](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getInviteLink). В свою очередь бот войдёт в беседу через этот [метод](https://vk.com/dev/messages.joinChatByInviteLink). Или я неверно понял ваш вопрос?